# Center SVG group element

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to center `g` element having `text` with `tspan` inside `svg` element using `d3` using below code.

```js
var rootSVGSize = d3.select("svg.root-svg").node().getBoundingClientRect()
var dataLabelSize = d3.select("g.data-label").node().getBoundingClientRect()

var x = rootSVGSize.width / 2;
var y = rootSVGSize.height / 2;

d3.select("g.data-label").attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg class="root-svg" width="180" height="200" style="border: black;border-style: solid;border-width: 1px;">
   <g class="data-label">
      <text alignment-baseline="middle" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 36px; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; fill: rgb(242, 200, 15);" text-anchor="middle">
         <tspan x="0" dy="0">1/1/2018</tspan>
         <tspan x="0" dy="41">3:00:00</tspan>
         <tspan x="0" dy="41">AM</tspan>
      </text>
      <title>1/1/2018 3:00:00 AM</title>
   </g>
</svg>
```

As you can see after executing above code, the group element is not centered correctly on x and y coordinates. How can I make group element center inside svg?

I am using `getBoundingClientRect` becuase I want to get size of `svg` at initial stage after assigning `width` and `height` that is before anything is rendred inside svg.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to take into account the `x` and `y` position of both the SVG container and the group:

```
var x = (rootSVGSize.x - dataLabelSize.x) + (rootSVGSize.width - dataLabelSize.width) / 2;
var y = (rootSVGSize.y - dataLabelSize.y) + (rootSVGSize.height - dataLabelSize.height) / 2;
```

That way, you can have any value you want for `alignment-baseline`, `dominant-baseline` and `text-anchor`, it doesn't matter, the group will be always centered.

Here is your code with that change:

```js
var rootSVGSize = d3.select("svg.root-svg").node().getBoundingClientRect()
var dataLabelSize = d3.select("g.data-label").node().getBoundingClientRect()

var x = (rootSVGSize.x - dataLabelSize.x) + (rootSVGSize.width - dataLabelSize.width) / 2;
var y = (rootSVGSize.y - dataLabelSize.y) + (rootSVGSize.height - dataLabelSize.height) / 2;

d3.select("g.data-label").attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg class="root-svg" width="180" height="200" style="border: black;border-style: solid;border-width: 1px;">
   <g class="data-label">
      <text alignment-baseline="middle" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 36px; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; fill: rgb(242, 200, 15);" text-anchor="middle">
         <tspan x="0" dy="0">1/1/2018</tspan>
         <tspan x="0" dy="41">3:00:00</tspan>
         <tspan x="0" dy="41">AM</tspan>
      </text>
      <title>1/1/2018 3:00:00 AM</title>
   </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a few changes in the svg, the most important: I've changed some values for the `tspan`'s `dy`. Also I'm using `dominant-baseline="middle"` instead of `alignment-baseline="middle"`. I hope it helps.

```js
var rootSVGSize = d3.select("svg.root-svg").node().getBoundingClientRect()
var dataLabelSize = d3.select("g.data-label").node().getBoundingClientRect()

var x = rootSVGSize.width / 2;
var y = rootSVGSize.height / 2;

d3.select("g.data-label").attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg class="root-svg" width="180" height="200" style="border: black;border-style: solid;border-width: 1px;">
   <g class="data-label">
      <text dominant-baseline="middle" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 36px; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; fill: rgb(242, 200, 15);" text-anchor="middle">
         <tspan x="0" dy="-41">1/1/2018</tspan>
         <tspan x="0" dy="41">3:00:00</tspan>
         <tspan x="0" dy="41">AM</tspan>
      </text>
      <title>1/1/2018 3:00:00 AM</title>
   </g>
</svg>
```